# Alfresco 4.2b Search doesn't work with Solr

Tags: solr, alfresco

I've some troubles with the search in alfresco, it doesn't work (for administrator or users)

The server version was initially 4.0d community edition. I tryied to upgrade it to 4.2b community edition (the default installer which embed all the component) on my dev virtual machine.

I had some problems with the certificate (I cannot access to https://example.com:8443/solr) so I upgraded the certifiate in alf_data with that procedure http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Replacing_Default_Certificate and it worked well

And I rebuilded all the index
http://deepak-keswani.blogspot.fr/2012/07/how-to-rebuild-solr-indexes-in-alfresco.html
(The folder have the same size so I think the data are indexed, if someone understand how I can make a custom search with solr folder, I would appreciate)

I activated the log in tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties and tomcat/webapps/share/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties
log4j.logger.org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrQueryHTTPClient=debug
but nothing appared in the log file.

I activated another log : I added a file dev-log4j.properties in shared/classes/alfresco/extension/ with that content :

```
log4j.logger.org.alfresco.web.scripts=debug
log4j.logger.org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts=debug
log4j.logger.org.alfresco.repo.jscript=debug
log4j.logger.org.alfresco.repo.jscript.ScriptLogger=debug
```

and I have a log result

```
21:42:39,375 DEBUG [org.alfresco.repo.jscript.Search] Failed to execute search: ((PATH:"/app:company_home/st:sites/*/*//*" AND (testours  AND (+TYPE:"cm:content" +TYPE:"cm:folder"))) AND -TYPE:"cm:thumbnail" AND -TYPE:"cm:failedThumbnail" AND -TYPE:"cm:rating") AND NOT ASPECT:"sys:hidden"
org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.lucene.LuceneQueryParserException: 11300004 Request failed 500 /solr/alfresco/afts?wt=json&fl=DBID%2Cscore&rows=502&df=keywords&start=0&locale=fr&fq=%7B%21afts%7DAUTHORITY_FILTER_FROM_JSON&fq=%7B%21afts%7DTENANT_FILTER_FROM_JSON
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrQueryHTTPClient.executeQuery(SolrQueryHTTPClient.java:398)
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrQueryLanguage.executeQuery(SolrQueryLanguage.java:49)
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrSearchService.query(SolrSearchService.java:348)
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.SearcherComponent.query(SearcherComponent.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.SubsystemProxyFactory$1.invoke(SubsystemProxyFactory.java:72)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy12.query(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at net.sf.acegisecurity.intercept.method.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.alfresco.repo.security.permissions.impl.ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.invoke(ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.java:46)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.alfresco.repo.audit.AuditMethodInterceptor.invoke(AuditMethodInterceptor.java:159)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy12.query(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.repo.jscript.Search.query(Search.java:803)
    at org.alfresco.repo.jscript.Search.query(Search.java:686)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:155)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:243)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:66)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c3._c20(file:/home/alfresco-4.0.d/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/search.get.js:1013)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c3.call(file:/home/alfresco-4.0.d/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/search.get.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:97)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c3._c22(file:/home/alfresco-4.0.d/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/search.get.js:1057)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c3.call(file:/home/alfresco-4.0.d/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/search.get.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName0(OptRuntime.java:108)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c3._c0(file:/home/alfresco-4.0.d/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/search.get.js:1060)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c3.call(file:/home/alfresco-4.0.d/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/search.get.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:393)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2834)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c3.call(file:/home/alfresco-4.0.d/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/search.get.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c3.exec(file:/home/alfresco-4.0.d/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/search.get.js)
    at org.alfresco.repo.jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.executeScriptImpl(RhinoScriptProcessor.java:492)
    at org.alfresco.repo.jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.execute(RhinoScriptProcessor.java:198)
    at org.alfresco.repo.processor.ScriptServiceImpl.execute(ScriptServiceImpl.java:212)
    at org.alfresco.repo.processor.ScriptServiceImpl.executeScript(ScriptServiceImpl.java:174)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryScriptProcessor.executeScript(RepositoryScriptProcessor.java:102)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractWebScript.executeScript(AbstractWebScript.java:1305)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.execute(DeclarativeWebScript.java:86)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer$3.execute(RepositoryContainer.java:422)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:433)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecute(RepositoryContainer.java:491)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecuteAs(RepositoryContainer.java:529)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScript(RepositoryContainer.java:345)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:377)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:209)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.servlet.WebScriptServlet.service(WebScriptServlet.java:118)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.GlobalLocalizationFilter.doFilter(GlobalLocalizationFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketWithOptionsProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1771)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

When I tryied the url :

> https://example.com:8443/solr/alfresco/afts?wt=json&fl=DBID%2Cscore&rows=502&df=keywords&start=0&locale=fr&fq={!afts}AUTHORITY_FILTER_FROM_JSON&fq={!afts}TENANT_FILTER_FROM_JSON

I had a 500 page issued from tomcat :

> Etat HTTP 500 - null java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   org.antlr.runtime.ANTLRStringStream.(ANTLRStringStream.java:75)
>   at
>   org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.parsers.FTSQueryParser.buildFTS(FTSQueryParser.java:108)
>   at
>   org.alfresco.solr.AlfrescoSolrDataModel.getFTSQuery(AlfrescoSolrDataModel.java:986)
>   at
>   org.alfresco.solr.query.AlfrescoFTSQParserPlugin$AlfrescoFTSQParser.parse(AlfrescoFTSQParserPlugin.java:80)
>   at org.apache.solr.search.QParser.getQuery(QParser.java:131) at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.prepare(QueryComponent.java:89)
>   at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:174)
>   at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:131)
>   at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1316) at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:338)
>   at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:241)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Then with my new log parameters, I tryied to rebuild it.

I've a lot of message http://depositfiles.com/files/4w85yegap but I din't see any elements

I tryied to open it with Luke (Lucene Index Toolbox) but I don't know how to use it ... But it says that I have 40k documents which can be true (but i can't check if they are well indexed)

**Update**

I retryied with alfresco 4.0d and it works. (I will a problem with the new version but it solves a part of my problem). My quick procedure for upgrade was to shutdown, backup and move 4.0d to another directory then copy alf_data, correct the certificate. Any clue ?

Does someone has a solution or a tips to continue ?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once solr worked with alfresco 4.0d (certificate problem, you can take the certificate of a newer version or generate your own). I upgrade alfresco to 4.2b with that procedure : http://www.fossoffice.com/en/2012/10/31/alfresco-community-upgrade/

Answer (score 2):

Are you 100% sure the solr index rebuild really succeeded ?

I have seen similiar search errors resulting from instances of types which have been removed from the dictionary.

Do you have the same extension types you had on 4.0 deployed on your 4.2 system ?

If in doubt, stop the system, wipe the index and rebuild again. Lay back and watch the logs for exceptions during the rebuild. In my case, the errors gave a hint about the missing types. In this case, either remove corresponding nodes before you rebuild the index or make the types available in the new system's data dictionary.

Comment: no I'm not sure that the rebuild succeeded. The search didn't work in 4.0 either (at the beginning it was functionnal and I don't know when it broke). I'll try to wipe the index and rebuild again. The new parameters in log can help me. If you have others log parameters, please transmit :) How can you make new types available in the data dictionnary ?

Comment: well i tryied and i didn't find entry in my log. I updated the question. Thank you andreas

Answer (score 2):

I guess, your query is not proper.

((PATH:"/app:company_home/st:sites/*/*//*" AND (testours  AND (+TYPE:"cm:content" +TYPE:"cm:folder"))) AND -TYPE:"cm:thumbnail" AND -TYPE:"cm:failedThumbnail" AND -TYPE:"cm:rating") AND NOT ASPECT:"sys:hidden"

Cause: testours is not a keyword in Lucene Query.
And there is no need to add "/*/*//*" to search at any level. 
Adding just **//*** will work. **PATH:"/app:company_home/st:sites//*"**

The Error you got 
-- Etat HTTP 500 - null java.lang.NullPointerException at org.antlr.runtime.ANTLRStringStream.(ANTLRStringStream.java:75)

When you tried hitting this link on browser
https://example.com:8443/solr/alfresco/afts?wt=json&fl=DBID%2Cscore&rows=502&df=keywords&start=0&locale=fr&fq={!afts}AUTHORITY_FILTER_FROM_JSON&fq={!afts}TENANT_FILTER_FROM_JSON

-- It's because, you forgot to add a **"query"** parameter  **q**="SOME_LUCENE_QUERY" to this.

Try this..
https://example.com:8443/solr/alfresco/afts?**q=TYPE:"cm:folder"**&wt=json&fl=DBID%2Cscore&rows=502&locale=fr&indent=on

Comment: well your last link (cm:folder) is functionnal. But I did'nt create my own query, I took this query from alfresco log but I don't know what to do with.

Comment: You didn't created this query ? ((PATH:"/app:company_home/st:sites/*/*//*" AND (testours AND (+TYPE:"cm:content" +TYPE:"cm:folder"))) AND -TYPE:"cm:thumbnail" AND -TYPE:"cm:failedThumbnail" AND -TYPE:"cm:rating") AND NOT ASPECT:"sys:hidden" Can you tell me the flow? What actions you performed & at what point you got this error ?  And before that 1) Check whether your Alfresco server is properly up and working? 2) Try to Search "alfresco" keyword as a free text through Advanced Search on Alfresco or Share interface. If SOLR is configured properly with Alfresco then you should get some result.

Comment: no I din't create it. I just made a search with the word testours in alfresco, I found the URL in the log. "alfresco" search doesn't work and alfresco works ... Search works in 4.0d and not in 4.2b version I don't know why (I already erased the index). thanks Deepak